# Adding all ScriptableObjects from folder to Dictionary in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have little problem here.
I'm trying to get all the ScriptableObjects (named "*InteractibleObjects*") from *Assets/Resources/InteractibleObjects* and put them to the Dictionary (named "*allInteractibleObjects*"), but Unity throws `NullReferenceExeption` on line with "*Adding 'objectToAdd' to the 'allInteractibleObjects' Dictionary*").
There is my code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Dictionary<int, InteractibleObject> allInteractibleObjects;

public string[] allInteractibleObjetsNames;

void Start()
{
    allInteractibleObjetsNames = Directory.GetFiles ("Assets/Resources/InteractibleObjects/", "*.asset")
       .Select(Path.GetFileName)
       .ToArray();// Getting files names

    for (int i = 0; i < allInteractibleObjetsNames.Length; i++) 
    {
        allInteractibleObjetsNames[i] = allInteractibleObjetsNames[i].Remove (allInteractibleObjetsNames[i].Length - 6);// Removing '.asset' from names
        Object objectInFolder = Resources.Load("InteractibleObjects/" + allInteractibleObjetsNames[i]);// Finding 'InteractibleObjects' by the name from 'allInteractibleObjetsNames'
        InteractibleObject objectToAdd = (InteractibleObject)objectInFolder;// From 'Object' to 'InteractibleObject'
        allInteractibleObjects.Add (i, objectToAdd);// Adding 'objectToAdd' to the 'allInteractibleObjects' Dictionary
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: You never assigned anything to `allInteractibleObjects`, you should do `allInteractibleObjects = new Dictionary<int, InteractibleObject>()` before the loop

Comment: Oh... Yes, now I see it. Thanks a lot